# Is there a closed formula for the finite sum $\sum_{i=0}^{r} {i \choose n}$?

Tags: combinatorics, summation, factorial

As I was doing a problem, I encountered this sum and I was wondering if there is a close form of this finite sum: (let $n$ be a positive integer and $r>n$)

$$\sum_{i=0}^{r} {i \choose n}$$

(where we intepret ${i\choose n}=0$ if $i< n$.)

Obviously this is equivalent to $\sum_{i=n}^{r} {i \choose n}$ but then I do not really have an idea of how to further this. I also tried to write out these terms as factorials but that seems to make this sum worse.

Could someone please help me? Thanks very much in advance!

Edit: I reckon this is actually a duplicate ([link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1713328/combinatorial-proof-of-the-identity-n1-choose-k1-k-choose-kk1-choose-k))

Comment: In this case you can to this.  Choose a reasonable number, say $n=5$.  Compute $$\sum_{i=5}^{r} {i \choose 5}$$ for $r=5,6,7,8$.  Then you will recognize the answers as binomial coefficients.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the identity

$$ \sum_{i=n}^{r}{i\choose n}={r+1\choose n+1}$$
which can be proved by induction on $r$:

For $r=n$ this is just the equality $${n\choose n}={n+1 \choose n+1}.$$
Suppose it is true for $r=k$. We get

$$ \sum_{i=n}^{k+1}{i\choose n}={k+1 \choose n} + \sum_{i=n}^{k}{i\choose n} = {k+1 \choose n} + {k+1 \choose n+1}={k+2 \choose n+1}$$
where the last equality uses a standard binomial identity.

Comment: Thank you so much for this brilliant answer!